# connection string Web config Problems ASP.net Vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, connection-string

This is my WebConfig XML:

```
<configuration> 
<location path="Manage.aspx">
<system.web>
<authorization>
<deny> users="?"</deny>
</authorization>
</system.web>
<connectionStrings>
<add>
name="myConnectionString" 
connectionString="Data Source=EMBRYOLOGIST;Initial Catalog=ARTSQL;Integrated Security=True"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
</add>
</connectionStrings>
</location>
</configuration>
```

In my Web form I imported the following:

```
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Web.Configuration
```

When I run my code I keep getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." to my connection string.
The code is:

```
Private Sub Page_PreLoad(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles   Me.PreLoad
Dim ConStrng As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("myConnectionString").ConnectionString
        If Not IsPostBack Then
        Dim strlst As String = "SELECT filenum, cast(Filenum as nvarchar (10)) + ' - ' +  Fname + ' ' +  Sname + ' ' +  Lname As FullName FROM ARTSQL.dbo.TblReg"
        Dim con As New SqlConnection(ConStrng)
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
        lst.Items.Add(New ListItem("Select Patient Record", ""))
        lst.AppendDataBoundItems = True
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.CommandText = strlst
        cmd.Connection = con
        Try
            con.Open()
            lst.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            lst.DataTextField = "FullName"
            lst.DataValueField = "Filenum"
            lst.DataBind()

        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        Finally
            con.Close()
            con.Dispose()
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by changing the whole XML format in the web config file,

The old one was,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration> 
<location path="Manage.aspx">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
<connectionStrings>
<add name="myConnectionString" connectionString="DataSource=EMBRYOLOGIST;Initial Catalog=ARTSQL;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"></add>
</connectionStrings>
</location>
</configuration>
```

The new one is,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<startup> 
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
</startup>
<connectionStrings>
<add name="ARTSQLConStrng" connectionString="DataSource=EMBRYOLOGIST;Initial Catalog=ARTSQL;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False />
</connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Ref.: [ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.connectionstrings%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 0):

I thing your code is true but

You should try this:

```
string appSettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myConnectionString"].ToString();
```

and then update your xml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   <configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
   <appSettings>
        <add key="myConnectionString" value="your connection strings here"/>
   </appSettings>
  </configuration>
```

Actually like this "*appSettings node*"

Comment: I know that, but it is same logic :) You can add the appsetting node ;)

Comment: Sorry Osama, its not working, My interpreter does't recognize string appSettings!

Comment: Hmm alright, can you look here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2

Comment: yes, i figured out that,, I used Vb identifiers in the string connection but still its not working